# Increment a value in an int NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, nsmutablearray

I've an `NSMutableArray` as

```
self.valuesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 0],[NSNumber numberWithInt: 0],[NSNumber numberWithInt: 0],[NSNumber numberWithInt: 0], nil];
```

As you can see it's initialized with `0` now If I want to increment `3` at index `2` how can I do it? I was trying to do it like

```
self.valuesArray[2] = [self.valuesArray objectAtIndex:2]+3;
```

but that's not the right way.

I've also tried doing this

```
[self.valuesArray[2] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.valuesArray[2] intValue]+3]];
```

but I got error that:

> Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Are you sure using an Objective-C collection class is the best thing to do?  You might want to consider a plain ol' C array, allocated with `malloc()` and released with `free()` if it changes size.  It would be way easier and quicker to manipulate than using `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this it will work.

```
int valueInc = [[self.valuesArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue] + 2;
NSNumber *numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:valueInc];

[self.valuesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:numberValue];
```